# Call one class' methods from another class

Tags: java

Here is my current code:
How do I call the methods to a different class?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class WordSelect {
    private Random r;

    public void selectHundred(String[]w5000, String[] w100) {
        r = new Random();     
        int i = 0;

        while (i < w100.length) {
            int random = r.nextInt(w5000.length);
            w100[i] = w5000[random];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: javascript is not java - edit your tags

Comment: Do you want to choose 100 _unique_ random items?  If so, then your logic is going to have to change.  As to your actual question, I'm not sure I "get it."

Comment: Do yourself a favor and help us help you by reading [ask]

Comment: let me try re explain so the thing is the code above is supposed to select 100 random words out of 5000 words and i have long created other classes that tackle the 5000 words. the 100 selected words are supposed to be put in an array of 100 indices.

Comment: Do you want to know how to return the array of the 100 Strings back to a calling module?

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create object of WordSelect and call the selectHundred method from a different class? If so, you may do the following

```
//This should be in the MainClass.java file
package test;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WordSelect ws = new WordSelect();


        String[] w5000 = new String[10];//replace this and the following 10 lines with your w5000

        w5000[0] = "a";
        w5000[1] = "b";
        w5000[2] = "c";
        w5000[3] = "d";
        w5000[4] = "e";
        w5000[5] = "f";
        w5000[6] = "g";
        w5000[7] = "h";
        w5000[8] = "i";
        w5000[9] = "j";



        String[] w100 = ws.selectHundred(w5000); // I believe you already have w5000, and you will the 100 random words in the w100
        for(int i=0;i<w100.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(w100[i]);
        }

    } 
}
```

but you need to change your existing program to the following so that the method can return the array of 100 strings

```
//This should be in the WordSelect.java file
package test;

import java.util.Random;

public class WordSelect {
    private Random r;

    public String[] selectHundred(String[]w5000) {
        r = new Random();     
        int i = 0;
        String []w100 = new String [5];

        while (i < w100.length) {
            int random = r.nextInt(w5000.length);
            w100[i] = w5000[random];
            i++;
        }

        return w100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question or are you looking for something else?

Comment: I hadn't compiled the code. I have replaced with working code. Just replace your w5000 and the two code should be in separate Java files.